# Check Input field empty or not for dynamic text field Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to validate validate multiple text field in angularjs controller function. I am using angular js 1.5.6
Here html code

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
<div ng-repeat="data in datas track by $index">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
                   name="info[]"
                   id="info[$index]"
                   ng-model="sendInformation.info[$index]" required>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="" ng-click="getValue()">Get Value</a>
{{result}}
```

Ande here is js code

```
 myApp.controller('Controller', function($scope) {

    $scope.sendInformation = {
    info: []
}

    $scope.datas = [
      {"id":'1'},
      {"id":'1'},
      {"id":'1'},
    ];

    $scope.getValue = function()
    {
      if($scope.sendInformation.info == null)
      {
        $scope.result = "Empty ____ Field";
      }
      else
      {
        $scope.result = "Ok";
      }
    }

  });
```

And I made a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZvrvzNwMwDSDHfHDrqGs?p=preview
I don't understand how to get the dynamic text value for validate that it is empty or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just convert it into a form. Give them unique names using `ng-attr-name="info-{{data.id}}"` (E.g: If the id is 1 the name will get evaluated to `name="info-1"`), then add a `ng-disabled` attribute to the button, since we have added `form.$invalid` inside the `ng-disabled`, the required attribute of each input element, if empty will set the `form.invalid` to true, unless we fill up all the input boxes! Like shown below.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);

      myApp.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.errorMessage = "";
        $scope.sendInformation = {
        info: []
    }
        $scope.datas = [
          {"id":'1'},
          {"id":'2'},
          {"id":'3'},
        ];
        $scope.getValue = function(form){
          var errors = "";
          for(var x of form.$error.required){
            errors = errors + x.$name + " ";
          }
          if(form.$invalid){
            $scope.errorMessage = "Fields " + errors + "are required!";
          }else{
            $scope.errorMessage = "";
          }
        }
        
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="Controller" ng-init="disabled=false;">
    <form name="form">
    <div ng-repeat="data in datas track by $index">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
                       ng-attr-name="field-{{data.id}}"
                       id="info[$index]"
                       ng-model="sendInformation.info[$index]" required>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button href="" ng-click="getValue(form);disabled=true;">Get Value</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>{{errorMessage}}</span>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But i don't get which one is empty.

Comment: @MahfuzShishir can you check now?

Comment: First time my button is disable. But is there not possible that when i will click button then it will show me which field is empty?

Comment: @MahfuzShishir This was not mentioned in the question, I updated the latest requirement in my answer, but please handle future issues by yourself!